# Why are items in stack view taking too much space in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uistackview

I made a profile area where it has some buttons and information about the person like followers and their posts:

[image]

But I was advised to make using multiple horizontal/vertical stackviews as it (a) is easier to manage for different sized screens and (b) is easier to constrain as a whole in the view. I made the exact copy and all the items (like the textViews or images) are taking up so much more space than they need to which makes the whole thing so much bigger, then when I try and space stuff out or in, everything just either goes on top of one another or it gets bigger. Could someone explain this behaviour? Here's the same thing just using the stackviews:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the '@username' textview is taking up so much space bother horizontally and vertically and I cannot even change that in the inspector as it just defaults back. The stack view hasn't got any constraints on it at all at the moment so no constraints are acting on it either.

Comment: give username a height constraint and make stackview fill proportionally.

Comment: How would I make it fill proportionally and how would I give it a height as if I add a constraint it doesn't affect anything and when I just increase the height normally it goes back to 0

Comment: No, don't use fill proportionally. You say "*The stack view hasn't got any constraints on it"* ... you need to decide how you want to constrain the stack view in order to understand the layout.

Comment: It shouldn't need any constraints to make whatevers inside of it act the way you want it to act should you?

Comment: @Nathan -- One issue... By default, `UITextView` has no intrinsic height. If you are not giving it an explicit height constraint, disable Scrolling and it will fit to the text.

Comment: @DonMag I used a label and the filled it proportionally